# Sort values in MySQL using HAVING clause and IN function

Tags: mysql

I have this portion of code with user's phone extensions:

```
GROUP BY IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION)
HAVING Ext IN (207, 213, 235, 214, 226, 218, 224, 227, 216)
```

It works fine, and it sorts values in ASC order ( 207, 213, 214..) Is it possible to sort values in different order? Something like this:

( 235, 207, 218 .. )

Comment: What is EXT in this?

Comment: You should not rely on any order unless an order by clause is used. See @EvanCarrol answer below.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Ext is alias from SELECT statement

Comment: There is a function for that: `ORDER BY FIELD(Ext, 235, 207, 218, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're putting the `EXT IN` a HAVING clause, but this should work.

```
WHERE IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION)
  IN (207, 213, 235, 214, 226, 218, 224, 227, 216)
GROUP BY IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION)
ORDER BY ext=235 DESC, ext=207 DESC, ext=218 DESC, ext;
```

Comment: @Lennart long day =(

Comment: I was using HAVING clause because Ext is an alias, and I couldn't use it in WHERE clause. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Blackcoat77 so just type the unaliased version out. `WHERE IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION) IN ...`

Comment: Sure! I did it. My mistake I didn't provide more info. You can edit your answer as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION)
  IN (207, 213, 235, 214, 226, 218, 224, 227, 216)
GROUP BY IFNULL(mxuser.EXTENSION, mxuser_1.EXTENSION)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET("207,213,235,214,226,218,224,227,216")
```